# Excel VBA. For each row in range, for each cell in row, for each character in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a VBA macro simple to absurdity.

For each row in range, then for each cell in row and then for each character in cell.

But it returns property or method not supported.

Now, to refer to each character in a cell in Excel VBA, it has to be defined as a range. So how is not a cell in a row in a range not a range object?

In all Excel examples the cells with Characters property have been referred to in absolute values. Like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`

Do I have to write a code of
`Worksheets("MySheet").Range("B1")`
...
`Worksheets("MySheet").Range("B2")`
...
...
`Worksheets("MySheet").Range("B250")`
To access characters or is there a way to access each character in a cell without Mid function?

By the way, Mid function looses formatting but I am looking for underlined characters.

My program is like this

```
Sub Celltest()
    For Each rw In Sheets("Joblist").Range("B1:D250").Rows
        For Each cel In rw.Cells
            For Each char In cel.Characters
                If char.Font.Underline = True Then MsgBox char
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

As a result I get message that a property or method is not supported.

Thank you!

David

Answer (score 3):

"Why is suddenly a part of a range object suddenly not a range?" That's not the issue.  The error is `Object doesn't support this property or method`.  That means that (basically) anything after the `.` is an object, so the error is telling you that *something* is up with how you're using `.Character`.

I did some quick searching around, and this works:

```
Sub Celltest2()
Dim rw As Range, cel As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim char    
    For Each rw In Sheets("Joblist").Range("B1:D250").Rows
        For Each cel In rw.Cells
            For i = 1 To Len(cel)
                'Debug.Print cel.Characters(i, 1).Text
                If cel.Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline = 2 Then
                    MsgBox (cel.Characters(i, 1).Text)
                End If
            Next i
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I just looked up the [Characters Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff194098.aspx) documentation, and there is the answer of how to use `.Characters`. The issue is how `.Characters` is used with the range - no sophisticated skills or knowledge necessary.  Just use the VB Error messages.

Comment: If you read my post you would see that I quoted the Characters Object documentation as it refers to cell objects defined with absolute values. You failed to respond to this part of my message, hence your arrogant tone.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to reset the range.  Check the code again, I put the sheet name and range back as you had it.  This works for me without issue, here's a [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/s7vEVB2.jpg).

Comment: That is not a problem. I spotted it and fixed myself. Your code works. At least while you iterate through it with F8. It does stop though when it reaches the underlined character. I will check it again. Thank you for your input.

Comment: P.S. You can read about my whole deal on my website: http://www.boxvan.co.nf/about.html All I wanted was to add underlined text to website as well and not just filter out postcodes.

Comment: I'm not sure if you know how, as you pointed out this is a super simple code so you could show your issue, but you can place the characters with underline into a text document, Excel cell, an Array, etc. instead of just having a message box prompt what character is underlined.

Answer (score 1):

Two things I noticed. 1. Characters is not a collection, so For Each won't work. 2. Font.Underline is not Boolean. Try something like:

```
Sub Celltest()
    Dim rw As Excel.Range
    Dim cel As Excel.Range
    Dim char As Excel.Characters
    Dim I As Long
    For Each rw In Sheets("Joblist").Range("B1:D250").Rows
        For Each cel In rw.Cells
            For I = 1 To cel.Characters.Count
                Set char = cel.Characters(I, 1)
                If char.Font.Underline <> xlUnderlineStyleNone Then MsgBox char.Text
            Next I
        Next
    Next
    Set rw = Nothing
    Set cel = Nothing
    Set char = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, this ended up with Unable to get Count property for Characters class. By the way, how is .Underline not a boolean? See Excel VBA help example: 
        With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
            .Value = "abcdefg"
            .Characters(3, 1).Font.Bold = True
        End With

Comment: I was able to reproduce the Characters.Count problem you describe when the cel has a formula instead of literal text. When the cell has a formula can you get character-by-character underlines? My experience is no, but if you know how I'd like to learn. My code runs for literal text, so you could add a test: IF cel.HasFormula THEN ...  Font.Underline is an enum with different values corresponding to single underline, double underline, no underline, etc.